# Django admin forms add fields dynamic

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to add fields dynamic.
I am using Django 1.11.2

I did:

```
class AdminOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):

    product1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ManagerProduct.get_products_qs(), required=True)
    quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, required=True)
    price1 = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=c.DECIMALS, min_value=0.01, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        exclude = ['date_added', 'date_updated']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for x in range(100):
            x += 2
            self.fields['product' + str(x)] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ManagerProduct.get_products_qs(), required=False)
            self.fields['quantity' + str(x)] = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, required=True)
            self.fields['price' + str(x)] = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=c.DECIMALS, min_value=0.01, required=True)

            self.Meta.fields.append('product' + str(x))
            self.Meta.fields.append('quantity' + str(x))
            self.Meta.fields.append('price' + str(x))
```

Everything seems to be ok inside the instance,I see the fields, but in html they are not appearing.

I didn't declared any fieldsets and if I declare it I receive and error that the fields create in init are not recognize

Comment: You almost certainly want to look into [django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thank you